# Git Server Setup using Apache 2.2 on Windows 7

Tags: git, bash, apache, perl

**Environment** Windows 7 64-bit

**Software** Git 2.10, Apache 2.2, Python 3.3.5, Strawberry Perl 5.24, Libgti2 0.22, Open LDAP

Git Server setup has been done. The `httpdf.config` file from Apache 2.2 has config entry

```
ScriptAlias "/git" "../interceptor.pl
```

After a few validations, the Perl script calls `httpbackend` using code `system(path to httpbackend)`

With this, git is supposed to execute pre-receive and post-receive hooks in bash.

But I am getting getting error

> Counting objects: 3, done.
>       Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>       Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
>       Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 308 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
>       Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
>       remote:       0 [main] bash 17820 C:\Program Files\Git\bin..\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - add_item ("\??\C:\Program Files\Git", "/", ...) failed, errno 1
>       remote: Stack trace:
>       remote: Frame        Function    Args
>       remote: 000FFFF9BB0  0018007164E (00180273652, 00180224DD9, 000FFFF9BB0, 000FFFF8B30)
>       remote: 000FFFF9BB0  00180046669 (000FFFFABE0, 000FFFF9BB0, 1D2156132A99C69, 00000000000)
>       remote: 000FFFF9BB0  001800466A2 (000FFFF9BB0, 00000000001, 000FFFF9BB0, 505C3A435C3F3F5C)
>       remote: 000FFFF9BB0  001800DF22B (00000000000, 000FFFFCE00, 001800CEE68, 1D215613B9BEF57)
>       remote: 000FFFFCC00  0018012D735 (00000000000, 00000000000, 001800C753E, 00000000000)
>       remote: 000FFFFCCC0  00180046CE5 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
>       remote: 00000000000  0018004590C (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
>       remote: 000FFFFFFF0  001800459A4 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
>       remote: End of stack trace
>       remote:       0 [main] bash 17708 C:\Program Files\Git\bin..\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - add_item ("\??\C:\Program Files\Git", "/", ...) failed, errno 1
>       remote: Stack trace:
>       remote: Frame        Function    Args
>       remote: 000FFFF9BB0  0018007164E (00180273652, 00180224DD9, 000FFFF9BB0,     000FFFF8B30)
>       remote: 000FFFF9BB0  00180046669 (000FFFFABE0, 000FFFF9BB0, 1D215613BB15B5D, 00000000000)
>       remote: 000FFFF9BB0  001800466A2 (000FFFF9BB0, 00000000001, 000FFFF9BB0, 505C3A435C3F3F5C)
>       remote: 000FFFF9BB0  001800DF22B (00000000000, 000FFFFCE00, 001800CEE68, 1D2156144A312D3)
>       remote: 000FFFFCC00  0018012D735 (00000000000, 00000000000, 001800C753E, 00000000000)
>       remote: 000FFFFCCC0  00180046CE5 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000,     00000000000)
>       remote: 00000000000  0018004590C (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
>       remote: 000FFFFFFF0  001800459A4 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
>       remote: End of stack trace
>       To http://localhost:8113/git/MyDemo.git
>       9a34da9..939214d  master -> master

Due to this error, hooks are not getting executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar issue has already been reported. See below thread for discussion and workarounds for the same.

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/493

Also, see following Cygwin faq: [What applications have been found to interfere with Cygwin?](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.bloda)

Comment: I have followed this links. no luck.:)

Comment: This is a bug in new version. had moved  back to Git 1.9. issue solved